# What does it mean that a target IP is active in nmap

Tags: networking, nmap

The following is from the map pages of nmap - `-Pn (No ping)` under this is written

> Proper host discovery is skipped as with the list scan, but instead of
> stopping and printing the target list,
> Nmap continues to perform requested functions as if each target IP is active.

What does target IP is active means above? 
Does it simply mean that nmap will not perform a ping to the host?